# Why does Windows 10 prefer IPv4 over IPv6?

Tags: windows-10, ipv6

I'm running the latest version of Windows 10 as of this writing (1903) and I have a working dual-stack connection. If I ping the hostname of a dual-stack device from the command line, Windows prefers the IPv4 address. If I turn off IPv4, it will use the IPv6 address. According to numerous sources (including [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1249588)), Windows should prefer IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1295130), I followed these steps to get a trace of the network stack:

```
netsh trace start provider=Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP level=5 keywords=ut:TcpipRoute
ping -n 1 www.google.com
netsh trace stop
netsh trace convert %TEMP%\NetTraces\NetTrace.etl
```

The resulting text file contained the following line:

```
[2]0910.3710::2019-08-10 01:27:15.198580000 [Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP]IP: Address pair (::ffff:10.0.12.67, ::ffff:172.217.7.132) is preferred over (fd85:741f:6df1:212:50df:dc26:f469:4d4c, 2607:f8b0:4004:800::2004) by SortOptions: 0, Reason: Prefer Matching Label  (Rule D 5.0).
```

The key part of that is

```
Reason: Prefer Matching Label
```

This is described in [RFC 3484](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) Section 5 "Source Address Selection". Basically, prefixes can have "labels", and a source/destination address pair where the source and destination labels match is preferred over a pair where they do not match.

I can see the prefix/label mappings on my computer by running

```
netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies
```

I get

```
Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
        50      0  ::1/128
        40      1  ::/0
        35      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
        30      2  2002::/16
         5      5  2001::/32
         3     13  fc00::/7
         1     12  3ffe::/16
         1     11  fec0::/10
         1      3  ::/96
```

As my source IPv6 address, fd85:741f:6df1:212:50df:dc26:f469:4d4c, is a ULA address (I'm using NPt to allow failover between two different WAN connections), it falls within fc00::/7 and gets a label of 13. My destination address is within ::/0 and gets a label of 1. Those do not match, hence preferring IPv4 where they both fall within ::ffff:0:0/96 and get a label of 4.

To fix this, I just need to add a prefix policy that sets my source address's label to 1. I can do that by running the following command in an administrative command prompt:

```
netsh interface ipv6 add prefixpolicy fd00::/8 3 1
```

That adds a policy for fd00::/8 (the entire ULA prefix) which has a precedence of 3 and a label of 1. Here's the updated prefix policy table:

```
Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
        50      0  ::1/128
        40      1  ::/0
        35      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
        30      2  2002::/16
         5      5  2001::/32
         3     13  fc00::/7
         3      1  fd00::/8
         1     12  3ffe::/16
         1     11  fec0::/10
         1      3  ::/96
```

And now when I ping a dual-stack hostname, it prefers the IPv6 address.